# How are Facebook Event Dates calculated

Tags: facebook, date, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I live at GMT. I've created an event on facebook at 00:00. When I query the graph api without access token, it returns 00:00. When I use an access token, it return 07:00.

There's a 2nd event I didn't create. It starts at 00:00 on the facebook page. When I query it without an access token, it returns 00:00. When I use an access token, it returns 08:00

My friend lives at GMT+2. To him, the second event appears the same as to me.

How are facebook event dates calculated? Given a GMT timestamp, how can I determine if an event is ongoing?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the weird world of the Facebook Graph API.

What you are most likely experiencing are permission and localisation issues.To remove the privacy bug, goto graph.facebook.com , click your feed api link on the Graph Page. This will generate an access token that gives you the exact same access you would experience if you'd logged into Facebook directly.

Your privacy settings may differ for applications, or hte people who have generated the events may block applications. In any case this helps remove one potential cause of the problem.
 (As opposed to logging in as an application).

With regards to the time offset, this is down to the API. You'll need to handle the offset yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the permission issue. When someone looks at the facebook event page, they see the same time everywhere in the world right? But the api returns localized time? If I enter an event myself now, shouldn't the localized time match the facebook page time?

Comment: People will see the time localised to their time setting. Thats most likely something you can extract from their profile page (Http://graph.facebook.com/me).

Comment: when you view this event with your access token. Do you see the time as 08:00 ? https://graph.facebook.com/205810062526?access_token= (you need to add the access token)

Comment: I see it as 08:00 (I'm GMT) If I go without the access key it says 00:00 which would be pacific time.

Comment: I'm GMT too... Is there anyone here from USA that could check this please?

Comment: my friend lives in GMT+2 and he sees 00:00 without and 08:00 with access token. So is there any localization going on?